# How to append an image where you using play framework?

Tags: jquery, playframework

This is my appending code. But it gives an error 404 image not found. I do use play framework in my project. Can I know the correct way?

```js
$('#div').append('<a id="imgID" class="img-styles" href="javascript:void(0)"> <img src="/public/images/help.jpg" class=" img-responsive" alt="img"> </a>');
```

Comment: You are doing it right - the appending part. What about the image's location and how you are accessing it?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy You are changing the original code buddy. Careful.

Comment: Why did you revert your question back, when we corrected all your mistakes?

Comment: image location is correct

Comment: Well if you get a 404 it seems you are accessing the image the wrong way.

Comment: When you put a `/` in front, then it is relative to the domain. Are you sure there's a HTTP / HTTPS server running? And the image is there in the `public` directory, which is in the root folder?

Comment: on top of actvator (play framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the play framework's documentation on [accessing assets](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/Assets), the directory structure looks like this:

```
public
 └ javascripts
 └ stylesheets
 └ images
```

Which is what you have currently. And to access them, you need to use:

```
GET  /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
GET  /liabilities/*file          controllers.Assets.at(path="/foo", file)
```

Which means, the path should be:

```
/assets/images/help.jpg
```

You should replace the `<img />`'s `src` attribute this way:

```
<img src="/assets/images/help.jpg"
```

Let me know if it works.